# JBoss EAP6 Connection to external HornetQ Implementation doesn't work, but does with JBoss 7.1.1

Tags: java, spring, jboss, jms, hornetq

I am trialing the JBoss AS EAP6.

However I have system solution that has been implementated using JBoss AS 7.1.1. and an external HornetQ 2.1.14 implementation. This works successfully with JBoss 7.1.1, but EAP 6 doesn't connect to HornetQ.

I am running as localhost. is it a case this just doesn't work, or am I missing something and the configuration is wrong?

**HornetQ configuration:**

**hornetq-beans.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<deployment xmlns="urn:jboss:bean-deployer:2.0">

   <bean name="Naming" class="org.jnp.server.NamingBeanImpl"/>

   <!-- JNDI server. Disable this if you don't want JNDI -->
   <bean name="JNDIServer" class="org.jnp.server.Main">
      <property name="namingInfo">
     <inject bean="Naming"/>
      </property>
      <property name="port">${jnp.port:1099}</property>
      <property name="bindAddress">${jnp.host:localhost}</property>
      <property name="rmiPort">${jnp.rmiPort:1098}</property>
      <property name="rmiBindAddress">${jnp.host:localhost}</property>
   </bean>

   <!-- MBean server -->
   <bean name="MBeanServer" class="javax.management.MBeanServer">
      <constructor factoryClass="java.lang.management.ManagementFactory"
           factoryMethod="getPlatformMBeanServer"/>
   </bean> 

   <!-- The core configuration -->
   <bean name="Configuration" class="org.hornetq.core.config.impl.FileConfiguration">
   </bean>

    <!-- The security manager -->
   <bean name="HornetQSecurityManager" class="org.hornetq.spi.core.security.HornetQSecurityManagerImpl">
      <start ignored="true"/>
      <stop ignored="true"/>
   </bean>

    <!-- The core server -->
   <bean name="HornetQServer" class="org.hornetq.core.server.impl.HornetQServerImpl">
      <constructor>
     <parameter>
        <inject bean="Configuration"/>
     </parameter>
     <parameter>
        <inject bean="MBeanServer"/>
     </parameter>
     <parameter>
        <inject bean="HornetQSecurityManager"/>
     </parameter>        
      </constructor>
      <start ignored="true"/>
      <stop ignored="true"/>
   </bean>

   <!-- The JMS server -->
   <bean name="JMSServerManager" class="org.hornetq.jms.server.impl.JMSServerManagerImpl">
      <constructor>         
     <parameter>
        <inject bean="HornetQServer"/>
     </parameter>         
      </constructor>
   </bean>


</deployment>
```

**hornetq-configuration.xml**

```
<configuration xmlns="urn:hornetq"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="urn:hornetq /schema/hornetq-configuration.xsd">

   <clustered>true</clustered>

   <paging-directory>${data.dir:../data}/node-a/paging</paging-directory>

   <bindings-directory>${data.dir:../data}/node-a/bindings</bindings-directory>

   <journal-directory>${data.dir:../data}/node-a/journal</journal-directory>

   <journal-min-files>10</journal-min-files>

   <large-messages-directory>${data.dir:../data}/node-a/large-messages</large-messages-directory>

   <connectors>      
      <connector name="netty">
     <factory-class>org.hornetq.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnectorFactory</factory-class>
     <param key="host"  value="${hornetq.remoting.netty.host:localhost}"/>
     <param key="port"  value="${hornetq.remoting.netty.port:5445}"/>
      </connector>

      <connector name="netty-throughput">
     <factory-class>org.hornetq.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnectorFactory</factory-class>
     <param key="host"  value="${hornetq.remoting.netty.host:localhost}"/>
     <param key="port"  value="${hornetq.remoting.netty.batch.port:5455}"/>
     <param key="batch-delay" value="50"/>
      </connector>
   </connectors>

   <acceptors>
      <acceptor name="netty">
     <factory-class>org.hornetq.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyAcceptorFactory</factory-class>
     <param key="host"  value="${hornetq.remoting.netty.host:localhost}"/>
     <param key="port"  value="${hornetq.remoting.netty.port:5445}"/>
      </acceptor>

      <acceptor name="netty-throughput">
     <factory-class>org.hornetq.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyAcceptorFactory</factory-class>
     <param key="host"  value="${hornetq.remoting.netty.host:localhost}"/>
     <param key="port"  value="${hornetq.remoting.netty.batch.port:5455}"/>
     <param key="batch-delay" value="50"/>
     <param key="direct-deliver" value="false"/>
      </acceptor>
   </acceptors>

   <broadcast-groups>
      <broadcast-group name="bg-group1">
     <group-address>231.7.7.7</group-address>
     <group-port>9876</group-port>
     <broadcast-period>5000</broadcast-period>
     <connector-ref>netty</connector-ref>
      </broadcast-group>
   </broadcast-groups>

   <discovery-groups>
      <discovery-group name="dg-group1">
     <group-address>231.7.7.7</group-address>
     <group-port>9876</group-port>
     <refresh-timeout>10000</refresh-timeout>
      </discovery-group>
   </discovery-groups>

   <cluster-connections>
      <cluster-connection name="my-cluster">
     <address>jms</address>  
     <connector-ref>netty</connector-ref>
         <retry-interval>500</retry-interval>
         <forward-when-no-consumers>true</forward-when-no-consumers>
         <max-hops>1</max-hops>
         <discovery-group-ref discovery-group-name="dg-group1"/>
      </cluster-connection>
   </cluster-connections>

   <security-settings>
      <security-setting match="#">
     <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="guest"/>
     <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="guest"/>
     <permission type="consume" roles="guest"/>
     <permission type="send" roles="guest"/>
      </security-setting>
   </security-settings>

   <address-settings>
      <!--default for catch all-->
      <address-setting match="#">
     <dead-letter-address>jms.queue.DLQ</dead-letter-address>
     <expiry-address>jms.queue.ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
     <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
     <max-size-bytes>10485760</max-size-bytes>       
     <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
     <address-full-policy>BLOCK</address-full-policy>
         <redistribution-delay>1000</redistribution-delay>
      </address-setting>
   </address-settings>



</configuration>
```

**JBoss EAP 6 Configuration**

**standalone-ha.xml**

key parts of the file are below:

```
<extensions>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.clustering.jgroups"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.configadmin"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.connector"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.deployment-scanner"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.ee"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.ejb3"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.jaxrs"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.jdr"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.jmx"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.jpa"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.logging"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.mail"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.modcluster"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.naming"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.osgi"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.pojo"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.remoting"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.sar"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.security"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.threads"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.transactions"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.web"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.webservices"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.weld"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.snowdrop"/>
</extensions>

<interfaces>
    <interface name="management">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:127.0.0.1}"/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="public">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}"/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="unsecure">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.unsecure:127.0.0.1}"/>
    </interface>
</interfaces>

<socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
    <socket-binding name="management-native" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.native.port:9999}"/>
    <socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}"/>
    <socket-binding name="management-https" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.https.port:9443}"/>
    <socket-binding name="ajp" port="8009"/>
    <socket-binding name="http" port="8080"/>
    <socket-binding name="https" port="8443"/>
    <socket-binding name="jgroups-diagnostics" port="0" multicast-address="224.0.75.75" multicast-port="7500"/>
    <socket-binding name="jgroups-mping" port="0" multicast-address="${jboss.default.multicast.address:230.0.0.4}" multicast-port="45700"/>
    <socket-binding name="jgroups-tcp" port="7600"/>
    <socket-binding name="jgroups-tcp-fd" port="57600"/>
    <socket-binding name="jgroups-udp" port="55200" multicast-address="${jboss.default.multicast.address:230.0.0.4}" multicast-port="45688"/>
    <socket-binding name="jgroups-udp-fd" port="54200"/>
    <socket-binding name="modcluster" port="0" multicast-address="224.0.1.105" multicast-port="23364"/>
    <socket-binding name="osgi-http" interface="management" port="8090"/>
    <socket-binding name="remoting" port="4447"/>
    <socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712"/>
    <socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713"/>
    <outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
        <remote-destination host="localhost" port="25"/>
    </outbound-socket-binding>
</socket-binding-group>
```

Comment: can you clarify a bit about it "not working", what errors do you get? EAP6 is AS7.2, and differences to 7.1.1 should be quite minor. also.. I'm not seeing any hornetq conf on your EAP6 configuration?

Answer (score 2):

That won't be compatible.. The newer library can't talk to an older server.

Up to HOrnetQ 2.2, we wouldn't support different versions at all on the protocol, and we started taking care of compatibility after 2.2... so what you're trying to achieve won't work.